# Trying to understand navigation properties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, navigation-properties

I have a question regarding navigation properties in EF Core which I can't seem to figure out. If i have a table, and a related table:

```
Person
=========
PersonId    
Name    
Surname    
RoleId

Role
=========
RoleId
RoleName
```

Now I implement the models for it in C#

```
public class Person
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int PersonId {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public string Surname {get; set;}
   public int? RoleId { get; set; }
   public virtual Role Role { get; set;}
}

public class Role
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

Is that a correct implementation? Specifically, I'd like to know what happens if I leave out

```
    public int? RoleId { get; set; }
```

from the Person table? Would that make a difference?
Also, what difference does it make if I add the following to the Role class:

```
public virtual List<Person> Persons {get; set;}
```

How does that change things?

Thank you

Comment: so are you using code first?

Comment: No, database first.

Comment: then you should not modify auto generated code.

Comment: Well, it wasn't auto generated code. I manually coded the models according to an existing database. I couldn't use migrations/scaffolding because it is a MySQL Database and there is no scaffolding support for MySQL as far as I am aware.

Comment: But anyway, my question is more theoretical. The code and tables I supplied on my post are not real anyway - I am simply trying to get a better understanding of navigational properties, because from all I've read, i'm still a bit unsure about some points.

Comment: suggest look into [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity,namespaces)

Comment: If you write your models by hand it is still code first even when the database exists. Having a Persons collection is possible but but i would discourage adding it because it is potentially big and is usually not needed as a whole. Only add collections if it makes sematically sense like Order->OrderItems. EF-Core somewhat supports references without duplicated foreignkeyproperty in the class with a lot of limitations.